# How to covert Javascript DataView object back to python bytes type?

Tags: javascript, python, backbone.js, python-traitlets

In one of my projects, I'm passing a serialized python instance as bytes type to the Javascript front end. At the javascript side When I console.log the `this.model.get('MyInstance')` it returns `MyInstance` as a data view object. Now I want to pass this instance back to the python kernel. My problem is that I am not able to get bytes type from the Data View object. A simple example would be something like this.

```
import pickle

def Hello():
    print('hi')

a = pickle.dumps(Hello)

print(type(a))
print(a)
```

Output:

```
<class 'bytes'>

b'\x80\x04\x95\x16\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8c\x08__main__\x94\x8c\x05Hello\x94\x93\x94.'
```

What am I trying? :

**Step-1**

passing bytes to the javascript front end

b'\x80\x04\x95\x16\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8c\x08__main__\x94\x8c\x05Hello\x94\x93\x94.'

**Step-2**

It look likes when Javascript receives the bytes type it converts it to DataView

**Step-3**

In this case, I need to convert the Data view object back to bytes before passing it to the python kernel.

**Step-4**

Pass bytes back to python kernel.

I am using

trait lets to update the javascript backbone.js model.

```
MyInstace = Bytes(sync=True)
```

How to solve this problem please help.